# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip'

Tags: gradle

macbook pro macOS 12.2.1
android studio 2021.2.1 Patch 1
It works well in my company yesterday, I take the computer to home and create a new project or open the available project, when sync the project it show the error: "Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip'."
I try to "invalidate caches.." it doesn't work
I check the .gradle/wrapper/dists folder and it has the 7.4.2 folder, I download gradle-7.4.2-all.zip and move to .gradle/wrapper/dists/7.4.2, It doesn't work
I config the "Build,Execution,Deployment"->"Build Tools"->"Gradle" choose Specified location and set to the locale position, it still doesn't work
I try to delete .gradle folder and "invalidate caches..", it doesn't work.....
I thought maybe the problem is the AndroidStudio can't access network, and try to update Android SDK in android studio(install a new SDK Platforms), it works well
It's so weird...anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve the problem by remove the Android Studio's Cache. the folder is `/Users/myMac/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/`